# When to use $\mathbf{P}$ , and when to use $\mathbb{P}$ as the symbol for probability?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I am trying to make myself some notes in preparatino for my FRM examination. Because I did a little mathematics and mathematical statistics at uni, I am getting very impatient with the inconsistent notations usen in FRM prescribed learning material. Having glanced through some many a probability theory books, and financial mathematics books, i have noticed that the mathematicians often use the $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbf{P}$ symbols, while most statisticians just stick to using $\mathbf{P}$ , or $\mathrm{P}$ . At first I thought that its just a matter of choice, but then I noticed that in some financial mathematics texts, that both $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathrm{P}$  are sometimes used in the same expression? Typo, choice, or are the two symbols used for different purposes?

Answer (score 5):

No difference--one can use either $P$ or $\mathbb P$ or $\mathbf P$ or $\Pr$ or...

Answer (score 4):

In the theory of Markov chains, the transition matrix is often denoted $P$ so there it is clearer to use some other symbol like $\mathbb P$ for probability. But such decisions are up to the author, and will vary from person to person.

Answer (score 1):

They are probably using one symbol to denote the risk-adverse measure and the other to denote the risk-neutral measure.  Often authors use $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, respectively, but sometimes $\tilde{\mathbb{P}}$ is used for the risk-neutral measure.  However, there's no reason why the author can't use the notation in your question.

See [Girsonov's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) and the [Radon-Nikodym theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem)

Answer (score 0):

Bland $P$ can also clash with event names. $M, N, P$ are out as event names, otherwise you get $P(P)$. Same goes for e-xpectation operator. $E$ can also be an e-vent (or the full space). Consider $E[1_E]$ and $E[1_P]=P(P)$. But, yes: "De gustibus non est disputandum".